# Screen Text Input in Python Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input, turtle-graphics

Simple program using `onkey()`. When I add `screen.textinput()`, the keyboard stops listening/responding after the screen input executes, and I'm not sure why:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color("blue")
player.shape("turtle")
player.penup()

def goForward():
    answer = int(screen.textinput("Turtle Program", "Enter forward in pixels"))
    player.forward(answer)

def goBackward():
    player.backward(5)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(goForward,"Up")
turtle.onkey(goBackward, "Down")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `textinput()` method does its own `listen()` to get control of keyboard input.  So you need to redo your `listen()` call after the `textinput()`:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def goForward():
    distance = screen.numinput("Turtle Program", "Enter distance in pixels", default=5)
    screen.listen()
    player.forward(distance)

def goBackward():
    player.backward(5)

screen = Screen()

player = Turtle()
player.shape('turtle')
player.color('blue')
player.penup()

screen.onkey(goForward, 'Up')
screen.onkey(goBackward, 'Down')
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the code below....

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()

player = Turtle()
player.color("blue")
player.shape("turtle")
player.penup()
answer = int(screen.textinput("Turtle Program", "Enter forward in pixels"))


def goForward():
    player.forward(answer)


def goBackward():
    player.backward(5)


screen.listen()
screen.onkey(goForward, "Up")
screen.onkey(goBackward, "Down")
screen.exitonclick()
```